# cannot break out of while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Trying to do a while loop, but it repeats even after I try to break it:

```
while True:        
    
    switch = int(input("Choose card to switch: "))
    if switch == "1":
             deck1.add_card(hand1.pop_card())
             deck1.shuffle()
             hand1.add_card(deck1.pop_card())
             break

    elif switch == "2":
               deck1.add_card(hand2.pop_card())
               deck1.shuffle()
               hand2.add_card(deck1.pop_card())
               break

    else:
              print("invalid input")
              continue
```

The code between "if" and "break" works fine, but I just go back to being asked to choose  a card. Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're passing the input through `int()`, so it is an integer, and cannot equal a string such as `"1"`.

Comment: I've already tried removing int(), it's still repeating. Since the other code works fine, this cannot be the problem anyway.

Comment: If that's true, then you need to share code with the actual problem, because that's the whole issue with the code you shared.

Comment: What I mean is that the code after the if statements work regardless. The issue is the looping, which I don't understand, as I try to "break" the loop.

Comment: If you remove the `int()`, then this code will absolutely break out of the loop.  If your code isn't doing that, then you must have some other issue, which we can't help solve unless you show us the real code.

Answer (score 0):

Integer not equal string, that's why else statement print invalid input and while loop continue again.
Code:

```
while True:        
    switch = int(input("Choose card to switch: "))
    if switch == 1:
         deck1.add_card(hand1.pop_card())
         deck1.shuffle()
         hand1.add_card(deck1.pop_card())
         break

    elif switch == 2:
           deck1.add_card(hand2.pop_card())
           deck1.shuffle()
           hand2.add_card(deck1.pop_card())
           break

    else:
          print("invalid input")
          break
```

Comment: Please indent the code properly.

Comment: Tried it, still loops

Comment: @Pr3daton if you want break it, just change else continue to break

Answer (score 0):

The most likely answer is that you're receiving integers from the user but conditionally checking against strings. Change the `if` conditions to be `1` and `2` instead of `"1"` and `"2"`.

In general, if you're working with complicated structures of `while` loops and `if` clauses, this might be a better way to achieve what you're after:

```py
repeat = True
while repeat:
    switch = int(input("Choose card to switch: "))
    if switch == "1":
        deck1.add_card(hand1.pop_card())
        deck1.shuffle()
        hand1.add_card(deck1.pop_card())
        repeat = False
    elif switch == "2":
        deck1.add_card(hand2.pop_card())
        deck1.shuffle()
        hand2.add_card(deck1.pop_card())
        repeat = False
    else:
        print("invalid input")
```

While maybe not the most Pythonic approach, this is a good way to trace the logic of complex conditional structures.

Again, your problem is most likely just that you're receiving integers from the user (`int(input("Choose card to switch: "))`) and checking against strings (`if switch == "1"`).

You should first try changing this like so:

```py
while True:
    switch = int(input("Choose card to switch: "))
    if switch == 1:
        deck1.add_card(hand1.pop_card())
        deck1.shuffle()
        hand1.add_card(deck1.pop_card())
    elif switch == 2:
        deck1.add_card(hand2.pop_card())
        deck1.shuffle()
        hand2.add_card(deck1.pop_card())
    else:
        print("invalid input")
```

Try that before using `repeat = True` and `while repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking an integer input but in if-condition you are comparing it with a string value.

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out: This code worked in Jupyter Lab and didn't loop. But in Spyder 4.1.4 it did for some reason. Still unsre why. But hey, got it now. Thanks for the input

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).